# Is Files.copy a thread-safe function in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have a function, that's purpose is to create a directory and copy a csv file to that directory. This same function gets ran multiple times, each time by an object in a different thread. It gets called in the object's constructor, but I have logic in there to only copy the file if it does not already exist (meaning, it checks to make sure that one of the other instances in parallel did not already create it).

Now, I *know* that I could simply rearrange the code so that this directory is created and the file is copied *before* the objects are ran in parallel, but that is not ideal for my use case.

I am wondering, will the following code ever fail? That is, due to one of the instances being in the middle of copying a file, while another instance attempts to start copying that same file to the same location?

```
    private void prepareGroupDirectory() {
        new File(outputGroupFolderPath).mkdirs();
        String map = "/path/map.csv"
        File source = new File(map);
        
        String myFile = "/path/test_map.csv";
        File dest = new File(myFile);
        
        // copy file
        if (!dest.exists()) {
            try{
                Files.copy(source, dest);
            }catch(Exception e){
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

To sum it all up. Is this function thread-safe in the sense that, different threads could all run this function in parallel without it breaking? I think yes, but any thoughts would be helpful!

To be clear, I have tested this many many times and it has worked every time. I am asking this question to make sure, that in theory, it will still never fail.

**EDIT**: Also, this is highly simplified so that I could ask the question in an easy to understand format.

This is what I have now after following comments (I still need to use `nio` instead), but this is currently working:

```
   private void prepareGroupDirectory() {
        new File(outputGroupFolderPath).mkdirs();
        logger.info("created group directory");

        String map = instance.getUploadedMapPath().toString();
        File source = new File(map);
        String myFile = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(map) + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(map);
        File dest = new File(outputGroupFolderPath + File.separator + "results_" + myFile);
        instance.setWritableMapForGroup(dest.getAbsolutePath());
        logger.info("instance details at time of preparing group folder: {} ", instance);
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // copy file
            if (!dest.exists()) {
                String pathToWritableMap = createCopyOfMap(source, dest);
                logger.info(pathToWritableMap);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing
            // thread-safe
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could fail for that reason, but that doesn't mean the function is not thread-safe.

Comment: java.nio handles multi-threaded access better;  as much as possible, methods either work or throw an exception.  You’d be wise to replace `dest.exists()` with `Files.exists(dest.toPath())`.  In fact, you’d be wise to remove all use of java.io.File.  The bigger problem is that you have a race condition, since your exists check and your creation check are two separate operations;  it is possible for two threads to simultaneously observe the need to create the file.

Comment: Also may differ per operating system. If you look at the code it uses a FileSystemProvider  to get the job actually done.

Comment: So we all agree that this function could fail, so that the file does not even get copied once? As long as it gets copied in any of the threads, then I am fine

Comment: In Windows, it probably would get copied only once.  In any other operating system, you’d probably lose some data, when one thread overwrites what the other thread was doing.  I personally would use a Lock.

Comment: A lock would solve this problem? Never used one.

Comment: A [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) is a lot like synchronization, but unlike synchronization, a Lock can be interrupted.

Comment: Interesting. I will do this if you think it will make it where the function cannot fail

Comment: Actually, the "best" way is really to do the copy only once!

Comment: Touche. I was hoping I could get it to work in a good condition with what I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't.

What you're looking for is the concept of rotate-into-place. The problem with file operations is that almost none of it is atomic.

Presumably you don't just want 'only one' thread to win the race for making this file, you *also* want that file to either be perfect, or not exist at all: You would not want **anybody** to be able to observe that CSV file in a half-baked state, and you most certainly wouldn't want a crash halfway through generating the CSV file to mean that the file is there, half-baked, but its mere existence means it prevents any attempt to write it out properly. You can't use `finally` blocks or exception catching to address this issue; someone might trip over a powercable.

So, how do you solve all these problems?

You do **not** write to `foo.csv`. Instead you write to `foo.csv.23498124908.tmp` where that number is randomly generated. Because that just isn't the actual CSV file anybody is looking for, you can take all the time in the world to finish it properly. Once it is done, then you do the magic trick:

You rename `foo.csv.23498124908.tmp` into `foo.csv`, and do so **atomically** - one instant in time `foo.csv` does not exist, the next instant in time it does and it has the complete contents. Also, that rename will only succeed if the file didn't exist before: It is impossible for two separate threads to both rename their `foo.csv.23481498.tmp` file into `foo.csv` simultaneously. If you were to try it and get the timing just perfect, one of them (arbitrary which one) 'wins', the other one gets an IOException and doesn't rename anything.

The way to do this is using `Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOptions.ATOMIC_MOVE)`. ATOMIC_MOVE is even kind enough to flat out refuse to execute if somehow the OS/filesystem combination simply does not support ATOMIC_MOVE (they pretty much all do, though).

The second advantage is that this locking mechanism works even if you have multiple entirely different apps running. If they all use `ATOMIC_MOVE` or the equivalent of this in that language's API, only one can win, whether we're talking 'threads in a JVM' or 'apps on a system'.

If you want to instead avoid the notion that multiple threads are both simultaneously doing the work to make this CSV file even though only one should do so and the rest should 'wait' until the first thread is done, file system locks **are not the answer** - you can try (make an empty file whose existence is a sign that some other thread is working on it) - and there's even a primitive for that in java's `java.nio.file` APIs. The `CREATE_NEW` flag can be used when creating a file, which means: Atomically create it, failing if the file already exists with concurrency guarantees (if multiple processes/threads all run that simultaneously, one succeeds and all others fail, guaranteed). However, CREATE_NEW can only atomically create. It cannot atomically write, nothing can (hence the whole 'rename it into place' trick above).

The problem with such locks are two fold:

- If the JVM crashes that file doesn't go away. Ever launched a linux daemon process, such as postgresd, and it told you that 'the pid file is still there, if there is no postgres running please delete it'? Yeah, that problem.
- There's no way to know when it is done, other than to just re-check for that file's existence every few milliseconds. If you wait very few milliseconds you're trashing the disk potentially (hopefully your OS and disk cache algorithms do a decent job). If you wait a lot you might be waiting around for no reason for a long time.

Hence why you shouldn't do this stuff, and just use locks within the process. Use `synchronized` or make a new `java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock` or whatnot.

---

To answer your code snippet specifically, **no that is broken**: It is possible for 2 threads to run simultaneously and both get `false` when it runs `dest.exists()`, thus both entering the copy block, and then they fall all over each other when copying - depending on file system, usually one thread ends up 'winning', with their copy operation succeeding and the other thread's seemingly lost to the aether (most file systems are ref/node based, meaning, the file was written to disk but its 'pointer' was immediately overwritten, and the filesystem considers it garbage, more or less).

Presumably you consider that a failing scenario, and your code does not guarantee that it can't happen.

NB: What API are you using? `Files.copy(instanceOfJavaIoFile, anotherInstanceOfJavaIoFile)` isn't java. There is `java.nio.file.Files.copy(instanceOfjnfPath, anotherInstanceOfjnfPath)` - that's the one you want. Perhaps this `Files` you have is from apache commons? I strongly suggest you don't use that stuff; those APIs are usually obsolete (java itself has better APIs to do the same thing), and badly designed. Ditch `java.io.File`, it's outdated API. Use `java.nio.file` instead. The old API doesn't have ATOMIC_MOVE or CREATE_NEW, and doesn't throw exceptions when things go wrong - it just returns `false` which is easily ignored and has no room to explain what went wrong. Hence why you should not use it. One of the major issues with the apache libraries is that it uses the anti-pattern of piling a ton of static utility methods into a giant container. Unfortunately, the second take on file stuff in java itself (`java.nio.file`) is similarly boneheaded API design. I guess in the java world, third time will be the charm. At any rate, a bad core java API with advanced capabilities is still a better than a bad apache utility API that wraps around the older API which simply does not expose the kinds of capabilities you need here.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I will use nio instead. And to be clear< you are saying that `reentrantLock` will fix this problem?

Comment: It's a tool you can use to fix this problem - locks (be it `synchronized` or one of the `j.u.c` package's Lock classes) can be used to write a system whereby different threads work together to ensure a sensitive codepath can only be executed by one thread at a time. It should be obvious how you can use that to ensure no 2 threads ever simultaneously write the same file. But that works only within one JVM, so if you're worried about multiple apps, you HAVE to use filesystem-based locking.

Comment: That'll be fine for me then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: > `There's no way to know when it is done.` [There is](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#register%28java.nio.file.WatchService,java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind%5B%5D,java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Modifier...%29).

Comment: Subscribing to a disk watch service for this is not a good plan at all. Those watch services are highly dependent on underlying OS and disk features and tend to slow everything to a crawl. For the impact you cause with this, that is definitely a case of using a bazooka to take down a mosquito.